# Problems when a disc is rotating at extreme speeds (theory)?

Tags: special-relativity, forces, rotational-kinematics

1. I was wondering the problems that would occur (aside from mechanical friction), when a disc rotates at high angular velocity. Is centripetal force an issue if high torque is applied on a disc (massive forces in the range of $100kN$ or $1MN$)?

Of course with the supply of high energy, just wanted to understand the problems that could occur when a disc rotates quite fast due to high torque.

2. Also, at what speed is a disc considered moving near the speed of light?

Comment: You may want to check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox

Comment: @dacodemonkey and Key, [this related answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147505/explanation-for-if-all-accelerated-systems-are-equivalent-then-euclidean-geome/147506#147506) gives a short calculation demonstrating the problem that Ehrenfest highlighted.

Comment: Quite a lot of careful materials engineering goes into disk brake design for ultra-high-speed vehicles precisely because of the centripetal force levels. It isn't just torque (acceleration) but the energy of the rotating material itself.

Comment: A disc is moving near the speed of light when relativistic effects become important. This depends on how sensitive your measurements are. For example, the fractional change in circumference is $sqrt(1-v^2/c^2)$. For a bicycle wheel 1m in diameter and spinning at 3 m/s, this is about 10nm. If that much change is important, the bicycle wheel is relativistic.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8659/2451 and links therein.