# A point on a disc travelling at the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed-of-light, reference-frames, rotation

This might be a duplicate of [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/8659/).

I had an interesting thought experiment: suppose that you have a disc of a 1 m radius, where a point P2 inside the disc travels at the speed of light. You have a point P2 on the edge of the disc, that should travel at the speed of light as well (given the fact that nothing can travel faster than the speed of light).

[image]

Applying the formulas of rotational speed, I get the following:

**For P<sub>2</sub>:**
v<sub>2</sub> = c
d<sub>2</sub> = Π
t<sub>2</sub> = Π/c

**For P<sub>1</sub>:**
d<sub>1</sub> = 2Π
t<sub>1</sub> = t<sub>2</sub>
v<sub>1</sub> = d<sub>1</sub> / t<sub>1</sub> = 2c -> **which is wrong**

This seems to be quite a paradoxical concept: the distance is known, the speed of the points must be equal, but the time in which the distance traveled must also be the same. So it seems to me, that somehow either space or time must be altered, so that the formulas remain valid.

Is this in any way linked to spacetime or the theory of general relativity? Is this a valid thought experiment, or am I missing something?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_paradox

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Euclidean geometry in non-inertial frame](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/201492/)

Comment: Don't assume $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: *"where a point P2 inside the disc travels at the speed of light"* - this isn't possible, in principle, according to SR so it's not a good place to start your thought experiment.